# Unable to see images inside posts in Android webview

Tags: android, webview, android-webview, android-websettings

I am trying to load a blog powered by Wordpress on Android WebView. While the content and the 'title' images are getting displayed, the images that are inside the posts (I mean opening a post from the displayed webpage) aren't getting displayed (all the text and even the ads are getting displayed). Viewing just the website on the web browser doesn't show such issues. I have tried the methods suggested in various other questions asked on this community regarding similar issues but failed to solve my problem.

Here is the code

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private WebView webView;
    private ProgressDialog mProgress;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.cuous_web_view);

        WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setAllowContentAccess(true);
        webSettings.setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
        webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        webSettings.setAppCacheEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setAppCachePath(this.getApplicationContext().
                       getCacheDir().getAbsolutePath());
        webSettings.setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
        webSettings.setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_DEFAULT);
        webSettings.setSupportZoom(true);
        webSettings.setUserAgentString("Android WebView");
        mixedContentIfRequired(webSettings);
        webSettings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

        webView.setWebViewClient(new CuousViewClient());
        webView.setWebChromeClient(new CuousChromeClient());
        webView.loadUrl("http://cuous.com/");
    }

    private void mixedContentIfRequired(WebSettings webSettings) {
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
             webSettings.setMixedContentMode(WebSettings.
                        MIXED_CONTENT_COMPATIBILITY_MODE);
        }
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK && webView.canGoBack()) {
            webView.goBack();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        if(mProgress != null && mProgress.isShowing())
            mProgress.dismiss();
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    private class CuousChromeClient extends WebChromeClient  {

        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) {
            if (mProgress == null) {
                mProgress = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
                mProgress.show();
                mProgress.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
            }
            mProgress.setMessage("Loading " + String.valueOf(progress) + "%");
            if (progress == 100) {
                mProgress.dismiss();
                mProgress = null;
            }
        }
    }

    private class CuousViewClient extends WebViewClient {

        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
            if(actionBar.isShowing()) {
                actionBar.hide();
            }
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {
            return true;
        }


        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
            view.loadUrl("javascript:var footer = document.getElementById(\"footer\"); footer.parentNode.removeChild(footer);");
        }

        @Override
        public void onReceivedSslError(WebView view, SslErrorHandler handler, SslError error) {
            if(handler != null) {
                handler.proceed();
            }
            else super.onReceivedSslError(view, null, error);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi I tried your link with mine code. I can see the images:[see the photo](https://ibb.co/jYpMza). Is it this that you want?

Then is that mine mainAcitivity:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private WebView view;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        view = (WebView) this.findViewById(R.id.webView);
        view.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        view.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        view.setWebViewClient(new MyBrowser());
        view.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html"); //try js alert
        view.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient()); // adding js alert support

    }
    private class MyBrowser extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            if (url.startsWith("tel:") || url.startsWith("sms:") || url.startsWith("smsto:") || url.startsWith("mailto:") || url.startsWith("mms:") || url.startsWith("mmsto:") || url.startsWith("market:")) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
                startActivity(intent);
                return true;
            }
            else {
                view.loadUrl(url);
                return true;
            }
        }
    }

    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && view.canGoBack()) {
            view.goBack(); //method goback()
            return true;
        }

        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
}
```

Can also ask what is the minimum SDK version?

**EDIT**

[This is what you want?](https://ibb.co/hLDLsv)

[This is what also get](https://ibb.co/mBwvQF)

**UPDATE_SHOULDURLOVERRIDING**

This is a piece of code that will do something else then just open the url in webview it controls of it is start with something like mailto....
what I mean with mailto:
In HTML you can do this: myname@gmail.com and on your pc it will open your outlook. If you have android and that piece of code isn't there it will give a error. If you have that piece of code it will ask in wich mailserivce do I need to open it.

**EDIT**
So if you load it by this methode it works?

```
@Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
```

instead of:

```
        view.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html"); //try js alert
```

Comment: Hi @Steven. Minimum SDK version is SDK 19 (Android 4.4 I think) onwards. As for the screenshot, I wasn't really referring to that. Perhaps I failed to explain it properly in the question though. Try opening the post which has "Health Kart Affiliates' mentioned. I was referring to the images that I should be seeing when I open that post.
By the way could you also explain what those lines within the `if` statement in `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` mean?

Comment: Thank you very much for explaining that bit in `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` and as for the screenshots (edit), yes I was referring to that. You can see the embedded images in the post in the web browser but for some reason it doesn't show up in the webview.

Comment: Yes I see but some images in the post show up . I have taken a look from where the photo need to be downloaded to show them in your page. If the scr='' start with "https://i0.wp.com/...." it won't load. It's very strange

Comment: Do you own that website?

Comment: not really, I took this up as a 'learning project'. The domain/website is owned by someone known to me. By the way I happened to find some project online. Just editing the loadUrl line of that project works. Problem is that I can't find any additional line of code in it. Maybe this link should help? I'd be really grateful if you or anybody else could explain what the important difference is.
[link](http://technoscripts.com/convert-website-into-android-app/)